# iOS Navigation Bar: Hidding the navigation bar and smooth transition

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a hierachy of view controllers inside a navigation controller and I for the root view controller I set the "hidden" property of the navigation controller bar to YES. All of its children have the "hidden" property set to NO. The problem is that I don't know where is the best place to hide the bar, because when I press the "back" button to return to the root view controller I can see how the navigation bar dissapears and the root view controller view's resizing and this is not a good user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you put your hide/unhide calls? The best place will probably be in viewWillAppear, such as in [this](http://blog.kvnd.me/post/9714565498/animating-hiding-showing-of-uinavigationbar) post.

Something like:

```
if (![self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden]) 
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I read the post and I fixed it using the     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
method. Thank you!